# Vim Regex Duplicate Lines Grouping

Tags: regex, sorting, vim, sed, awk

I have a log file like this:

```
12 adsflljl
12 hgfahld
12 ash;al
13 a;jfda
13 asldfj
15 ;aljdf
16 a;dlfj
19 adads
19 adfasf
20 aaaadsf
```

And I would like to "group" them like one of these two:

```
12 adsfllj, 12 hgfahld, 12 ash;al
13 a;jfda, 13 asldfj
15 ;aljdf
16 a;dlfj
19 adads, 19 adfasf
20 aaaadsf
```

Or

```
12 adsfllj, hgfahld, ash;al
13 a;jfda, asldfj
15 ;aljdf
16 a;dlfj
19 adads, adfasf
20 aaaadsf
```

And I am totally stuck. And if vim doesn't do it, I have sed and awk and bash too. I just don't really want to write a bash script, I want to increase my regex-fu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd just use awk:

```
awk '
  {
    sep = val[$1] ? ", " : ""
    val[$1] = val[$1] sep $2
  }
  END {for (v in val) print v, val[v]}
' log.file | sort > new.file
```

Comment: I don't have the faintest clue how this works, but it does, so this is a good reason for me to crack open a tutorial on awk to learn why. Bravo! My fu is ready to increase!

Comment: One odd feature of awk is how it does string concatenation: there is no concat operator (like `+` or `.`) -- place two variables side-by-side and the values will be concatenated. The operators (like `?:` above) generally work like C operators. Also, an unset variable acts like an empty string or numerically zero, thus false.

Answer (score 6):

In Vim you can use:

```
:%s/\(\(\d\+\) .*\)\n\2/\1, \2/g
```

which means: if a group of numbers is matched after a new line, remove the newline and place a comma instead. If you are not familiar with them, `\1` and `\2` are backreferences.

Unfortunately this only merges two occurrences at a time, so you'll have to run it multiple times before achieving your goal.

EDIT: one way to do it in a single go would be to cycle and exploit the fact that the as soon as the file doesn't match anymore an error is issued. The error is a bit annoying though, but I couldn't do better with a one-liner:

```
:while 1 | :%s/\(\(\d\+\) .*\)\n\2/\1, \2/g | :endwhile
```

Comment: Thanks this is also great, I gave you the upvote for points, his was just first...

Answer (score 2):

In Vim, I would use the command

```
:g/^\d\+/y|if+@"==getline(line('.')-1)|s//,/|-j!
```

if it is guaranteed that the first column always contains digital ids.

Otherwise, I would modify that if-condition as follows.

```
:g/^\S\+/y|if matchstr(@",@/)==matchstr(getline(line('.')-1),@/)|s//,/|-j!
```

Comment: @Peter:  It also performs well: both commands are much faster than UncleZeiv's substitutions loop or Benoit's sequence of commands, and apace with (or even a bit faster than) ZyX's script.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this, with a macro this time (I advise you to use another solution, this one just shows that there are plenty of ways to do it):

> `gg:%s/$/,`<kbd>enter</kbd>`qa0V?`<kbd>ctrl-r</kbd><kbd>ctrl-w</kbd>`\>\&^`<kbd>enter</kbd>`Jjq100@a:%s/.$//`<kbd>return</kbd>

explanation:

- `gg` => go to start of file
- `:%s/$/,` => append comma to every line
- `qa` => start recording a macro into register `a`
- `0V` => go to first column, and start linewise selection
- `?` => lookup backwards (you must have `set wrapscan`)

  - <kbd>ctrl-r</kbd> <kbd>ctrl-w</kbd> inserts word under cursor.
  - `\>` ensures end of word
  - `\&^` ensures pattern matches at start of line. You cannot put `^` at the beginning of the pattern, because if `incsearch` is set, then as soon as you have typed `^` then <kbd>ctrl-r</kbd> <kbd>ctrl-w</kbd> will print the word under cursor, which will have moved to the previous line.
- `J` will join all lines from the visual selection with spaces.
- `j` will go to next line
- `q` will stop recording macro
- `100@a` will play macro 100 times.
- `:%s/.$//` will remove trailing commas.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that this is a good idea to use regular expressions here. Same idea that you can find in @glenn jackman's solution written in vimscript will be the following:

```
function JoinLog()
    let d={}
    g/\v^\S+\s/let [ds, k, t; dl]=matchlist(getline('.'), '\v^(\S+)\s+(.*)') |
              \let d[k]=get(d, k, [])+[t]
    %delete _
    call setline(1, map(sort(keys(d)), 'v:val." ".join(d[v:val], ", ")'))
endfunction
```

You can keep the order instead of sorting:

```
function JoinLog()
    let d={}
    let ordered=[]
    g/\v^\S+\s/let [ds, k, t; dl]=matchlist(getline('.'), '\v^(\S+)\s+(.*)') |
              \if has_key(d, k) | let d[k]+=[t] |
              \else             | let ordered+=[k] | let d[k]=[t] |
              \endif
    %delete _
    call setline(1, map(copy(ordered), 'v:val." ".join(d[v:val], ", ")'))
endfunction
```