# How to use: g command in order to requirements?

Tags: regex, vim

There is a log file like this:

```
adsflljl    abc
hgfahld abc
ash;al  abc
a;jfda  cd
asldfj  cd
;aljdf  de
a;dlfj  dh
adads   ae
adfasf  ae
aaaads  hi
```

I would like to "group" them like this:

```
adsflljl,hgfahld,ash;al abc
a;jfda,asldfj   cd
;aljdf  de
a;dlfj  dh
adads,adfasf    ae
aaaads  hi
```

My way is use `%s/^\v(.*)\t(.*)\n(.*)\t\2/\1,\3\t\2`

I know that the use of replacement several times, i can achieve the above requirements.

But in
[Vim Regex Duplicate Lines Grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601324/vim-regex-duplicate-lines-grouping)

the way of user ib is

`:g/^\S\+/y|if matchstr(@",@/)==matchstr(getline(line('.')-1),@/)|s//,/|-j!`

I changed it to

`:g/\t\S\+$/y|if matchstr(@",@/)==matchstr(getline(line('.')+1),@/)|s//,/|j!`

But it doesn't work.Why ?How to use: g command in order to achieve the above requirements?

Comment: why not use a scripting language such as pyhton, ruby, perl or even a language such as Java for this?

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but because I am a beginner, do not understand these scripts can only be starting from scratch.

Comment: You can take a step to learn everything at any time.  `%!perl -nle '($d, $l) = split; $t{$l} .= ",$d"; END { print substr "$t{$_} $_", 1 for keys \%t; }'`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't fully understand the original `:g` command, and just messed around with it (though you're efforts are pretty close). That's dangerous; unfortunately, to become a Vim master, you have to take the time to dissect each subcommand. Only then will you gain the understanding that enables you to make it work for your situation.

#### Differences

- The original grouped on the *first* column (regexp: `^\S\+`); you're grouping on the *last* one. The `y`ank command includes the trailing newline, so the following `matchstr()` comparisons will fail. Just yank the line's text (sans newline) with `norm! y$`.
- Instead of joining with *above* lines, you're doing that to *below* lines; but that confuses the `:g` iteration. Instead, keep the direction, and just apply the substitution to the above line: `-s//,/`, then join the *current* line.

#### Result

This command produces the desired outcome:

```
:g/\t\S\+$/exe 'norm! y$'|if matchstr(@",@/)==matchstr(getline(line('.')-1),@/)|-s//,/|j!|endif
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind an error message this will work:

```
while 1 | %s;\v^(\S+)(\s+)(\S+)\_s*(\S+)\s+\3;\1,\4\2\3;g | endwhile
```

This keeps repeating until there are no more matches (the error).

Comment: ,Thank you! I know this method you can, I just want to know why not use changed g command.

Comment: To be honest, I could not get the `:g` command to function, whereas `:%s` (normally the same thing) did.

Answer (score 0):

You can do scripting with [vim](/questions/tagged/vim) as you can do it with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), [python](/questions/tagged/python) or whatever other language. In my opinion it's not as easy to develop big scripts with it but it's useful for cases like this one. But it's funny and you will learn something different. Here you have the script:

```
"" List with the unique keys (second field)
let l = []

"" Dictionary which its values will be a list with all first fields common 
"" to their keys.
let d = {}

"" Traverse the whole file line by line, split it with spaces and fill either 
"" the list and the dict.
for line in range(1, line('$'))
    let fields = split(getline(line))
    if ! has_key(d, fields[1])
        let d[fields[1]] = []
    endif
    call add(d[fields[1]], fields[0])
    if empty(l) || l[-1] != fields[1]
        call add(l, fields[1])
    endif
endfor

"" Delete the buffer content.
1,$delete

"" The list keep the keys ordered as in the original file. Get each one 
"" and extract for the dictionary the list of values and print them joined 
"" with commas.
for key in l
    let delem = d[key]
    call append(line('$') - 1, join(delem, ',') . ' ' . key)
endfor

"" Delete a traling newline from last line.
delete

"" Save and quit
wq
```

Run it like:

```
vim -u NONE -N -S script.vim infile
```

Note that I avoid the loading of special configuration values with `-u NONE`. Also the previous code is saved in `script.vim`. The file is modified in place and the result is:

```
adsflljl,hgfahld,ash;al abc 
a;jfda,asldfj cd
;aljdf de
a;dlfj dh
adads,adfasf ae
aaaads hi
```